# is there any word that means "current and upcoming"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms

I want to find a word that could mean current and upcoming but couldn't. Or is there any other shorter ways to describe it? can anyone help me?

Comment: Probably 'now and next' could be an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Sven Yargis inadvertently supplied the answer: **emergent** strongly suggests both present and future; e.g. "Execron, Boffex and Crudco are **emergent** players in the growing codswallop market." =]

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, though _emerging_ seems more appropriate. Something that is _emerging_ is starting to appear, while something that is _emergent_ is arising from interactions among smaller entities (cf. [_emergence_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) and in the context of Sven's article [_emergent democracy_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergent_democracy)).

Answer (score 0):

Try [*imminent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/imminent):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 About to happen:
> *they were in imminent danger of being swept away*

(Definition and link from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I think imminent satisfies upcoming but if "current" could be substituted with "currently ongoing" without loss of correctness in the sentence, imminent would be incorrect because it implies it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Tommy - 'Upcoming' means that *it hasn't happened yet*. You can't have it both ways; *currently ongoing* is incompatible with *it hasn't happened yet*.

Comment: Yes this is my point; imminent is incorrect because it's compatible with `upcoming` but not `current`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...find a word that could mean current and upcoming ... Or [other] shorter ways to describe it?

From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pending), *pending* has three senses that make it a suitable answer:

> - awaiting a conclusion or a confirmation
> - begun but not completed
> - about to happen; imminent or impending

([Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pending) and [collinsdictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pending)
include similar senses.) As you can see, the latter two senses correspond reasonably well to “current” things and “upcoming” things.

In spite of those dictionary entries, I tend to discount or disregard the “begun but not completed” sense, so I'm not able to enthusiastically back *pending* as an answer to the question.  In addition, many of the British English synonyms [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english-thesaurus/pending) suggests seem to me inappropriate or irrelevant, but you may find them worth considering:

> *unresolved, undecided, unsettled, unconcluded, uncertain, awaiting decision, awaiting action, undetermined, (still) open, hanging fire, (up) in the air, in limbo, in the balance, on ice, in reserve, in abeyance, ongoing, awaiting attention, outstanding, to be done, undone, not done, unattended to, unfinished, incomplete, left, remaining*  for first two senses, and
>   *imminent, impending, about to happen/be, forthcoming, upcoming, on the way, coming, approaching, looming, gathering, prospective, near, nearing, close, close at hand, in the offing, in the wind, to come, -to-be, anticipated, expected* for third sense

Other terms I think relevant include *[looming](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/looming)*, *[on the docket](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/docket)*, *[on deck](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_deck)*, *[pipelined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pipelined)*, *[near term](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near-term)*, and *[peri-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peri-#Prefix)*, a prefix meaning near, on, around.  However, none of the 132 [terms that begin with *peri-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_peri-) look applicable.

Answer (score 0):

*Current* and *upcoming* are at odds in most situations because something that currently possesses a particular status is already in place and thus fundamentally differs from something that hasn't yet acquired that status but will do so eventually. Consequently, a word meaning "current and upcoming" would have the same limited utility as a word meaning "being and becoming" would. Though language endlessly produces new words to fill newly perceived vacancies in its verbal arsenal, they have to be useful sufficiently often to prompt people to adopt them.

The practical problem facing a one-word synonym for "current and upcoming" is that the two ideas "current" and "upcoming" are important enough, different enough, and easy enough to express in a fairly compact form that people haven't felt the need to devise a single-word workaround for "current and upcoming." That may explain why no satisfactory one-word option for simultaneously indicating both states is in common use.

One alternative is to use the phrase "now and future," which does appear in the intended sense in some published writing, such as in Eugene Kennedy's book title [*The Now and Future Church: The Psychology of Being an American Catholic*](http://books.google.com/books?id=B3_tEeat24cC&q=%22now+and+future%22&dq=%22now+and+future%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3kgXVKP1Mcm8iwLFyYGoBg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1984), and in this instance from Gareth Stansfield, [*Iraqi Kurdistan: Political Development and Emergent Democracy*](http://books.google.com/books?id=FB4ErXPRRd0C&pg=PA11&dq=%22now+and+future%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rkkXVKu9MYmwjAKHlIHQBg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22now%20and%20future%22&f=false) (2003):

> The study is, in effect, a 'now' and 'future' appraisal, thereby bringing into contention those aspects of theory which may be described as analytical, and those which may be termed prescriptive.

On the other hand, the phrase "current and upcoming" appears in published writings, too. For example, from Mat Heyman, [*National Bureau of Standards: A National Resource for Science and Technology*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ELgdzgdFQL8C&pg=PA63&dq=%22explanation+of+some+of+the+current+and+upcoming+uses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vksXVO6gCKasigLDroG4BQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22explanation%20of%20some%20of%20the%20current%20and%20upcoming%20uses%22&f=false) (July 1979):

> *An explanation of some of the current and upcoming uses of computer technology in the supermarket, retail stores, and banking is offered in a new NBS pamphlet, **Automation in the Marketplace**.*

And from Tetsuya Tokano, [*Water on Mars and Life*](http://books.google.com/books?id=o8SVQscnVEQC&pg=PA84&dq=%22current+and+upcoming%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CEwXVIf4N6S5igLS-YCYAw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22current%20and%20upcoming%22&f=false) (2005):

> Several current and upcoming missions have instruments that will provide information on the mineralogy of Mars.

In fact, "current and upcoming" yields many more matches than "now and future" in a Google Books search once you clear away the irrelevant matches (such as the use of "now and future" in the sentence "Make the wrong choices now and future generations will live with a changed climate"), so it may be the most suitable phrase available.

I wouldn't use "now and next" unless I wanted to convey the particular idea that the item being described is both the current object of interest and the object next in line (to succeed itself).

Answer (score 0):

Such things could be described as being *du jour*

> popular, fashionable, or prominent at a particular time

[Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/du%20jour)

Although this can be used when describing past events (or the soup in cheesy French restaurants), when used in the present tense it implies that the subject is fresh and fashionable.

eg.

> London Grammar are the band *du jour*

Answer (score 0):

How about simply [pending](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pending)?

For a negative twist, try [impending](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impending) or [looming](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/looming).

Answer (score 0):

- **Word**: Trendy
- **Definition**: following the latest trends or fashions; up-to-date or chic:
- **Example**: "the trendy young generation."

Taken from: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trendy?s=t